# Change the appearance of grids in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, grids

I am asking if there is a command in the `pgfplots` package that changes the appearance of the grid in terms of kind of the lines. What I mean is how to change the kind of lines. I have read the documentation but I could not find anything on this issue.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As with most of the settings in `pgfplots`, you can set these things globally in the preamble using `\pgfplotsset`

For example

- minor ticks: `\pgfplotsset{minor grid style={dashed,red}}`
- major ticks: `\pgfplotsset{major grid style={dotted,green!50!black}}`
- *both* minor and major ticks: `\pgfplotsset{grid style={dashed,gray}}`

A complete MWE follows

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% grid style
\pgfplotsset{grid style={dashed,gray}}
\pgfplotsset{minor grid style={dashed,red}}
\pgfplotsset{major grid style={dotted,green!50!black}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
                             xtick={-4,-2,...,4},
                             minor xtick={-5,-3,...,5},
                 grid=both]
        \addplot {x^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why does the `\addplot` draw the parabola in blue and with the dots? Is that defined in the plot itself outside of this MWE?

Comment: @Andyc that's the defaults set by `pgfplots`